# How to send an Image stored in the cloud via Django EmailMessage as an attachment

Tags: django, image, django-views

I am trying to create an uber clone using Django where when a driver registers in our platform an email is sent to use to validate his account, in which I need to attach the image in the email which would be stored in an AWS S3 bucket.

```
def driver_confirmation_email(request, user, profile):
    content = f"""
A user has registered for the site and needs the approval to use our service.

User ID: #{user.id} 
First Name: {user.first_name},
Last Name: {user.last_name},
Email: {user.email},
Phone Number: {profile.mobile},
Date of Birth: {profile.date_of_birth},
Gender: {user.get_gender_display},
District: {user.district},
NIC Number: {user.nic_number}

Consider approving the user by this link http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/user/profiledriver/{user.id}/change/

"""

    license = open(profile.license.path)

    EmailMessage(
        f"Approval of the new user {user.first_name} {user.last_name}",
        content,
        'najaaznabhan@gmail.com',
        ['najaaznabhan@gmail.com'],
    ).attach(license).send()
```

This is currently my code where `user` is the registered user and the `profile` is any other related information of the user being registered.

For some reason, I am thrown with an error that the file can't be opened. Do we need to use `io.BytesIO` and create a buffer to hold the image and then attach it? I am not very sure how to get that done.

Just in case this is my profile models.py...

```
class ProfileDriver (models.Model):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(choices=[("M","Male"), ("F", "Female")], default="M", max_length=6)
    district = models.CharField(choices=CITY, default="CMD", max_length=11)
    nic_number = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    license = models.ImageField(upload_to="driverLicense")
    your_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="driverImages")
    total_income = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__ (self):
        return f"{self.user}"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: If it's for S3 you probably want to use [Django Storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html).

Comment: I do use Django storages and anything related to Django storages works fine, I'm referring to how can I attach the image stored in S3 in an `EmailMessage`. Are you aware of anything @dmitryro

Comment: Wait so I basically need to download the image from S3 into my local machine and then attach it to my Email using BytesIO?? Isn't there a more efficient way to do it rather than downloading it locally? @dmitryro